# random background in an express/nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I would like to use a random background in my express/nodejs app and I have done this simple script

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

var bg = getRandomInt(3);



router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {

var slug=req.url.replace(/^\//,'').replace(/\/$/,'');
if(slug==''){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages`', function (error, results, fields) {
        res.render('index', { title: title, year: year, bg:bg, pages: results });
    });
```

the problem is that the number on the variable bg gets computed only when I start the app and not at each refresh/visitor. I assume that this is a limitation of the template engine (handlebars) ? Do I need to use Handlebars {{math}} helper ?

I am sure the solution is trivial so thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: post the rest of your code, at least your express route/middleware which is serving 'index'. You'll want to generate the random number in each request.

Comment: my bad sorry, edited with the full route.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a random number each request, otherwise you'll end up serving the same random number to everyone since it was generated when the process started, and you're not changing it.

> I assume that this is a limitation of the template engine (handlebars)
>   ? Do I need to use Handlebars {{math}} helper ?

It's not a handlebars' limitation, the only thing you need to do is put: `var bg = getRandomInt(3);` inside your express route.

```
router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    var bg = getRandomInt(3); // Generate random each request
    var slug = req.url.replace(/^\//, '').replace(/\/$/, '');
    if (slug == '') {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM `pages`', function(error, results, fields) {
            res.render('index', {
                title: title,
                year: year,
                bg: bg,
                pages: results
            });
        });
    }

    /** ... **/
});
```

Comment: awesome..my bad but may be it will help other n00bs too :)

Comment: No problem! It may happen to anyone who is learning node/express :)